# Identifying whether some drivers are not collecting boarding passes

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test, mean

Here's the problem.  I work for a transportation company and we're trying to prove the following hypothesis: Drivers are allowing passengers on the vessel without taking taking their paper boarding passes.  The assumption is every passenger on the vessel purchased a pass, but some portion simply shows the driver a confirmation email.  Here's the data I have

Travel date: MM/DD/YYYY

Schedule:ABC (roughly 60 different schedules operate every day on different routes)

DriverID: NAME.  Drivers can operate different schedules.

Count(Passes): Total of the day's boarding passes

The dataset is the COMPLETE ticket count from January 1 through April 30, every ticket we've received.  How would I go about finding if the average of a given driver boarding pass count is significant from the population's average?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how many people rode the ferry? You could check if the number of passengers equaled the number of tickets.

Comment: We don't.  It's actually a pretty vast interline company, and tickets come from dozens of private agencies.  We NEED the physical boarding passes to track passenger counts and sometimes even to redeem revenue.  It's a pretty antiquated system and it's slowly improving, but we can't really change completely until the vendors also decide to change

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to find out if drivers aren't collecting tickets without knowing how many passengers there are. How much data do you have (how many days, how many drivers, how many trips / schedules / routes, etc.)?

Comment: I'm starting to think the same thing, since it's difficult to tell what the 'true' mean should be.  Couldn't I just compare the driver results against eachother?

Comment: I have complete data for January 1 - April 30, each day has about 60 entrys (one for each schedule) so roughly 120 days x 60 schedules = 7200 entries.  each row includes Schedule name, DriverID, Date, Ticket Count.

Comment: Please change your title to one that briefly indicates the nature of the problem. Your present title is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is not particularly clear. If the company is issuing passes, presumably you know how many were issued for a particular trip but you don't seem to mention having this number. Please clarify what data you have.

If you only have data for the number of passes collected each trip, but there's variation in the numbers of passengers at different times of day/days of week (and particular drivers are not limited to a very limited subset of them), then you *might* be able to infer a difference in the proportions that the different drivers are taking (by adjusting for other obvious drivers that relate to time or day). However, it won't tell you anything if they're all under by about the same proportion.